# Join numpy arrays of different dimensions and shapes

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis

I have 2 `arrays`, one has a shape of `(2,2)` and the other has a shape of `(2,2,2)`. I want to stack them together so that my final result can have a shape of `(3,2,2)`. I'll put an illustration of what I'm talking about

```
Array 1  ->    [ 1,2 ]      -> shape(2,2)
               [ 3,4 ]

Array 2  ->    [ 5,6 ]     [ 9,10  ]     -> shape (2,2,2)
               [ 7,8 ]     [ 11,12 ]
              

Final Array after stacking Arrays 1 and 2  ->  [ 1,2 ]       [ 5,6 ]     [ 9,10  ]    ->shape (3,2,2)
                                               [ 3,4 ]       [ 7,8 ]     [ 11,12 ]
```

Comment: It will be easier to solve and understand if you provide the _actual_ Python code you have tried, as well as the description.

Comment: Did you try anything? Learn anything from the resulting error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more flexible with dimension choices you can use `ravel` with `reshape`:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.arange(1, 5).reshape(2, 2)
arr2 = np.arange(5, 13).reshape(2, 2, 2)

stack = np.concatenate((arr1.ravel(),arr2.ravel())).reshape(3,2,2)
```

Output:

```
>>> stack
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],
    
       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]]])
```

Comment: If you reshape `arr1` to (1,2,2), you don't need the ravel step.

Comment: @hpaulj , Hey, That's true. I tried to attempt a solution where OP doesn't have to almost care about what dimensions, the input arrays are.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html), to stack your arrays along the **d**epth (third) axis:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 5).reshape(2, 2)
b = np.arange(5, 13).reshape(2, 2, 2)

c = np.dstack((a, b))
print(c)
#[[[ 1  5  6]
#  [ 2  7  8]]
#
# [[ 3  9 10]
#  [ 4 11 12]]]
print(c.shape)
#(2, 2, 3)
```

---

EDIT: To get your desired shape of `(3, 2, 2)`, you can still use `np.dstack`, but with transposed input and output:

```
c = np.dstack((a.T, b.T)).T
print(c)
#[[[ 1  2]
#  [ 3  4]]
#
# [[ 5  6]
#  [ 7  8]]
#
# [[ 9 10]
#  [11 12]]]
print(c.shape)
#(3, 2, 2)
```

Comment: I realised that I made a mistake in my question. np.dstack creates a 3rd column. However, I don't want a 3rd column. I want the final results to have a shape of (3,2,2). That's 3 arrays with a matrix shape of (2,2)

Comment: Shape (2,2,3) is 3 arrays with shape (2,2) as well, just indexed by the last instead of the first column. Apparently the other answer solved your problem.